# Putting words in Alphabetic order using string Tokenizer

Tags: java

I have to put words in Alphabetic order using string Tokenizer and String methods. I'm a beginner in Java so i only know like char, compare to, boolean operation, if statement, switch statement for,while loops, and String Tokenizer etc.... 
I have this so far.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Alphabetize
{
    // Establish Global Class-State Variables
    static StringTokenizer st;
    public static void main()
    {
        // Input Data
        inData();
        //Variable Assigment
        varAssign();
        //Process Data
        alphaOrder();
        //Output Information
        outPrint();
    }

    public static void inData()
    {
        // Input Data
        String n= "Hailee James Kate Emily Alex Jackie";
        st = new StringTokenizer (Hailee James Kate Emily Alex Jackie);
    }

     public static void varAssign()
    {
        //Process Data

    }

    public static void alphaOrder()
    {
        //Outprint Information
    }

    public static void outPrint()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: start by reading the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

The string tokenizer class allows an application to break a string into tokens. for your case you can use tokenizer to separate words and then you can use A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects you can find out more about referring these documents[1][2]

```
* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Alphabetize
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String n= "Hailee James Kate Emily Alex Jackie"; // try to use meaningful identifiers(instead of n use sentence or etc..)
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(n);
        List<String> sortedArrary = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    sortedArrary.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
}

Collections.sort(sortedArrary, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }
});
     System.out.println(sortedArrary.toString());
    }
}
```

- [1]:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String)
- [2]:
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Thanks for anwsering my questions!!